# JQuery Accordion Menu Change Arrow Icons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a complete Jquery novice but I've managed to put together an accordion menu for some help text. I have it currently so if you have one panel open and you click to open another, the first one will close. I've now included some arrows which change from facing right to down when you open a panel and vice versa.

The problem I'm having is when I click into another panel with the first one open, the icons do not change back to facing right. Hopefully someone will be able to point out where I'm going wrong as I've a tried a few things now and seem to have accomplished every scenario apart from the one I want.

Thanks.
Dan

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

      //Expands/collapses panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle(0);
   $("i",this).toggleClass("fa-angle-down");

      //Hides other panels
      $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp(0);
   $(".accordion-content").find("i").not($(this).next()).toggleClass("fa-angle-down");
 
   
    });
  });
```

```css
<style>
  .accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer;}
  .accordion-content {display: none;}
  .accordion-content.default {display: block;}

.pHeader {
 font: 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #555;
 text-transform: none;
 text-indent: 0px;
 letter-spacing: normal;
 word-spacing: 0px;
 white-space: normal;
 font-size-adjust: none;
 font-stretch: normal;
 margin-left: 0px;
 font-weight:normal;
}

.accordion-content p {
 font: 12px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #555555;
 text-transform: none;
 text-indent: 0px;
 letter-spacing: normal;
 word-spacing: 0px;
 white-space: normal;
 font-size-adjust: none;
 font-stretch: normal;
 margin-left: 10%;
}
 
.pUL {
 font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
 text-transform: none;
 text-indent: 0px;
 letter-spacing: normal;
 word-spacing: 0px;
 white-space: normal;
 font-size-adjust: none;
 font-stretch: normal;
 margin-left: 60px;
}

.accordion-toggle hr {
 height: 1px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 margin-top: -1px;
}

.accordion-toggle i {
 font-size: 27px;
 color:#999;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 15px;
 float: right;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<p style="font-size: 16px; width: 100%; text-align:center;">Frequent Asked Questions</p>

<div id="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">
   <span class="pHeader">Products</span><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-2x"></i>
  <hr noshade /></h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;">Example 1</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<hr noshade style="height:1px; background-color:#ccc; margin-left: 10%;" />
<p style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;">Example 2</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  

  
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle" style="padding-top: 10px;"><span class="pHeader">Orders</span><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-2x"></i><hr noshade /></h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
  <p style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;">Example 1</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <hr noshade style="height:1px; background-color:#ccc; margin-left: 10%;" />
  <p style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;">Example 2</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <hr noshade style="height:1px; background-color:#ccc; margin-left: 10%;" />
  <p style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;">Example 3</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    
  </div>
  
  
  </div>
```

Comment: can you please add complete html for accordion?

Comment: I've just added it in.

Comment: check answer please comment if it is not working with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(
        function() {

            var selectedPanel = $(this).next();

            // Hides other panels
            var otherPanels = $(".accordion-content").not(selectedPanel);
            otherPanels.slideUp(0);

            // Make other arrows turn right
            var arrows = otherPanels.prev().find("i");
            arrows.removeClass("fa-angle-down");

            // Expands/collapses panel
            selectedPanel.slideToggle(0);
            $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-angle-down");

        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove fa-angle-down from li it will make arrow right.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
$("#accordion i").removeClass("fa-angle-down");
      //Expands/collapses panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle(0);
      $("i",this).toggleClass("fa-angle-down");

      //Hides other panels
      $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp(0);
      $(".accordion-content").find("i").not($(this).next()).toggleClass("fa-angle-down");


    });
  });
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1pwge6vr/) https://jsfiddle.net/1pwge6vr/

Comment: Thanks for post. That works as expected but the icons do not change if you close the same panel, only if you open another panel.